# CUPS: The printer is unreachable at this time and the printer did not respond

Tags: cups, printer

I am getting a lot of printer unreachable messages but it does not tell me which printer is having issues. It only shows the job number. How do I get which printer is having problems?

```
W [02/Feb/2023:12:47:13 +1100] [Job 697860] The printer did not respond.
W [02/Feb/2023:13:29:14 +1100] [Job 697990] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [02/Feb/2023:13:31:26 +1100] [Job 697990] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [02/Feb/2023:14:25:13 +1100] [Job 698159] The printer is unreachable at this time
```

Comment: You might try `lpstat -u` or some other of its options to get info on your jobs.

Comment: Jobs aren't in the queue. Is there a way to determine where these print jobs are coming from?